# Load very heavy stream with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to read a very heavy JSON (over than 6000 objects) and store them on a hash map to insert it into my database later.

But the problem is that I face with OOM and that's cause from my heavy JSON, however GSON library should rid me from this situation, but it is not !!!

Any ideas?

```
public Map<String,String> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException 
{
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    Map<String,String> contentMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    Gson mGson = new Gson(); 

    contentMap = mGson.fromJson(reader, contentMap.getClass());

    reader.close();

    return contentMap;
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether GSON can do that, however Jackson can: it has a streaming API allowing you to do just that.

Comment: @fge So you suggest me to using Jackson?

Comment: Well, I have used both and have always preferred Jackson, now, YMMV...

Comment: @fge I'm sorry, Should I download it from [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)?

Comment: Well, see @NAYOSO's answer as to Gson's streaming API. If you are not settled yet, try both and pick the one you prefer ;)

Comment: If you are planning to store the whole feed in memory anyway in your map then what is the point of using the streaming api?

Comment: @digitaljoel So you mean OOM cause from map?

Comment: OOM is caused by running out of memory. If your objects are big and you store them all in memory you may run out of memory regardless of whether they are stored in a map or an object graph created by GSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience, yes you can use google GSON to stream JSON data this is an example how to do it :

```
APIModel result = new APIModel();
        try {
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(APIParam.API_001_PRESENT(
                    serial_id, api_key));
            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                Reader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(streamReader);
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {

                    String name = reader.nextName();

                    if (name.equals("result")) {
                        if (reader.nextString() == "NG") {
                            result.setResult(Util.API_001_RESULT_NG);
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (name.equals("items")) {
                        result = readItemsArray(reader);
                    } else {
                        reader.skipValue(); // avoid some unhandle events
                    }
                }

                reader.endObject();
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result.setResult(Util.API_001_RESULT_NG);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result.setResult(Util.API_001_RESULT_NG);
        }
```

readItemsArray function :

```
// read items array
    private APIModel readItemsArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        APIModel result = new APIModel();
        String item_name, file_name, data;
        result.setResult(Util.API_001_RESULT_OK);

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            item_name = "";
            file_name = "";
            data = "";
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equals("name")) {
                    item_name = reader.nextString();
                } else if (name.equals("file")) {
                    file_name = reader.nextString();
                } else if (name.equals("data")) {
                    data = reader.nextString();
                } else {
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
            result.populateModel("null", item_name, file_name, data);
        }
        reader.endArray();
        return result;
    }
```

API Model Class :

```
public class APIModel {
    private int result;
    private String error_title;
    private String error_message;
    private ArrayList<String> type;
    private ArrayList<String> item_name;
    private ArrayList<String> file_name;
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    public APIModel() {
        result = -1;
        error_title = "";
        error_message = "";
        setType(new ArrayList<String>());
        setItem_name(new ArrayList<String>());
        setFile_name(new ArrayList<String>());
        setData(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    public void populateModel(String type, String item_name, String file_name, String data) {
        this.type.add(type);
        this.item_name.add(item_name);
        this.file_name.add(file_name);
        this.data.add(data);
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getError_title() {
        return error_title;
    }

    public void setError_title(String error_title) {
        this.error_title = error_title;
    }

    public String getError_message() {
        return error_message;
    }

    public void setError_message(String error_message) {
        this.error_message = error_message;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ArrayList<String> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getItem_name() {
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(ArrayList<String> item_name) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFile_name() {
        return file_name;
    }

    public void setFile_name(ArrayList<String> file_name) {
        this.file_name = file_name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

before I use the streaming API from google GSON I also got OOM error because the JSON data I got is very big data (many images and sounds in Base64 encoding) but with GSON streaming I can overcome that error because it reads the data per token not all at once. And for Jackson JSON library I think it also have streaming API and how to use it almost same with my implementation with google GSON. I hope my answer can help you and if you have another question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: It took me at least 5 minutes to realize the `Util` class is an enum that would need to be written. In most cases, you need neither the `APIModel` nor the `Util` class--they are provided here as an example of an object that the user is trying to parse. Also, it's worth noting that underscores in variable/parameter/method names breaks [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) as well as [Android code conventions](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html).

Comment: @gmale yes I aware of that, I wrote this code last year, at the beginning of my java learning, and I just copy and pasted it to here, so please forgive me of that :), I'll try to rewrite if I have time! Thanks for your notice :)

Comment: @nayoso: no worries, I just posted that in case it can save the next person 5 minutes :)

Comment: note, I just stumbled on another good example of [using JsonReader in the Gson docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)