# How to decrease memory allocation?

Tags: java, android, android-memory, android-profiler

I am writing an android application. Because of the aim, I have to (insert)cache my 10 mb sized userlist to sqlite db. When the user trigger api call I send the inputstream to BufferedReader and use `char[] buffer = new char[2048];` as chunk because if i read inputstream line by line the script is not continuing(i think this causes from my 10mb body is a single line and its too large to read). When that happens my memory usage increses to 90mb from 10mb stable. code is below

```
private String getResult() {
    String Result = "";


    try {
   ....    
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int HttpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), CharsetNames.Utf8.value));
            String line = null;
            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            int count;
            while ((count = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String s = new String(buffer, 0, count);
                stringBuilder.append(s);

            }
            reader.close();
            Result = stringBuilder.toString();
        } else {
            Result = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Tools.ShowStandartErrorToast();
    }
    return Result;
}
```

1_ why when i red 10 mb body from apicall why my application memory usage(java) increases 80mb instead of 10mb and the solution?

After this method returns string result i use it to initialize a json object.
And then i use that json to initialize my Object Instances. After this operation memory usage decreases to 320 mb.

```
protected Result doInBackground(Parameter Parameter) {

    ...........
       ApiHelper = new ApiHelper(getSelectedService(), parameter.getAsJson());
       String resultString = ApiHelper.getResult();
       result = setResult(resultString);
    ...........
}
```

---

```
public class UserListResponse extends BaseResponse {

    public static final String UserList_FIELD_NAME = "UserList";
    public List<User> UserList;

    public UserListResponse(String baseStringResult) {
        try {
            this.baseJsonResult = new JSONObject(baseStringResult);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.baseJsonResult = new JSONObject();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void mapFields() {


        if (baseJsonResult.has(UserList_FIELD_NAME) && !baseJsonResult.isNull(UserList_FIELD_NAME)) {
            try {

                JSONArray jaPerson = baseJsonResult.getJSONArray(UserList_FIELD_NAME);
                UserList = new ArrayList<>(jaPerson.length());

                for (int i = 0; i < jaPerson.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject joPersonInfo = jaPerson.getJSONObject(i);
                    User pi = new User();
                    pi.init(joPersonInfo);
                    UserList.add(pi);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2_ If the reason is that i mostly use string fields how can i release these string fields. I think they keeps living even if i decleare them in a method.

I used System.gc() where ever its possible but it has no effect on memory usage.

Comment: if you read 10MB `stringBuilder` will take 20MB and then `Result` another 20MB ... also alocation of `s` in every iteration will also take cumulatively 20MB ... for 10MB JSON it obviously would be better to use some stream JSON parser

Comment: @Selvin is absolutely correct. Here are example solutions to follow:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902425/load-very-heavy-stream-with-gson

2. https://memorynotfound.com/gson-streaming-api-reading-and-writing-example/

Comment: still wating for a sample code which responses faslty for 10mb post body and decreases memory allocation after the usage of respnose class end :(

Comment: any of them worked when you give the stream to gson.fromJson() it dissappears, couldn't find any suggestion without chunking