# Android efficient way to read write segments from a large json file

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I'm doing a project where I have to read and write from a large json file and show the content in a list, modify data and save it back.

Currently I'm reading the entire file and serialising it with gson.

Is there an efficient way/library to read/write the data in chunks/pagination and then serialise/deserialise it without loading the entire file in memory?

Comment: JSON is really bad at the whole "update a huge file" aspect. Your best bet is probably to transform it into a format that's easier to manipulate. If you always edit distinct chunks, then even just separating each such junk into its own file will already make the task much easier.

Comment: JSON as any other markup language is OK to work with large files. You just should use the appropriate technique - stream/event/token based API instead of an Object Mapper. This is like working with large XML with SAX/StAX instead of DOM... See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868825/split-a-large-json-file-into-smaller-json-files-using-java/61918904#61918904 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Streaming API for JSON, be prepared to handle fairly low level details.

Supported by Jackson [0], also looks like streaming is supported by GSON [1]. Potentially useful GSON example [2]

---

- [0] https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi
- [1] https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming
- [2] [Load very heavy stream with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902425/load-very-heavy-stream-with-gson)